# Create more variables or calculate when passing arguments to function

Tags: java, function, libgdx, rendering, draw

So I have a performance question. Is it better to declare more variables and then pass them as arguments or to calculate it when passing it as an argument for a function. I'll give an example:

```
shapeRenderer.rect(gameWidth/32 -(border/2) + gameWidth/60,gameHeight/18 - (border/2), gameWidth/3 + border ,gameHeight/30 + border);
```

Since this function is being called every frame, does that mean it's being calculated, for 50 fps, 50 times over and over again? Would it increase performance if I declared new variables in the constructor, like:

```
float x = gameWidth/32 -(border/2) + gameWidth/60;
float y = gameHeight/18 - (border/2);
float width = gameWidth/3 + border;
float height = gameHeight/30 + border;
```

and then called the function:

```
shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height);
```

Since I have let's say 100 rectangles being drawn this would lead to 400 variables(every rectangle has different position and dimensions). Would that increase performance?

Comment: Is this one function call in an instance variable, that's invoked many times, or many calls in different places of the code?

Comment: It's one call that's invoked every frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rectangles have fixed dimensions/position than it would be better to pre calculate the values when initializing the rectangle, but if those value can change, you will have to recalculate everything.

**Suggestion:**

> As long as you don't have a performance issue, it's not advisable to
>   try fine tuning your application.

Comment: The dimensions are somewhat fixed. There are let's say 100 fixed dimensions for 100 rectangles and they will never change, so you suggest to declare 400 variables in the constructor then?

Comment: Declaring 400 variables is definitely not the way to go. If you have that many rectangles you should consider keeping those values in arrays. For ex. you could have 4 arrays of  type double: xCoordinates, yCoordinates, widths, heights.
But than again, I don't think you should be concerned about performance as long as your application works fine.

Comment: I like the arrays idea.ty

Answer (score 0):

Declaring new variables in the constructor should be faster. But it is also quite possible that due to the optimizations the JVM performs that you will feel no speed execution benefit .

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't. If you look at the java ByteCode the instructions will be the same.